# field_widget_form get value

Tags: 7, entities

I am creating a custom field and I am looking to get the value of a textfield during node creation. In the callback I need to get the value of the textfield, how do I do this?

```
function field_zoekproduct_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
      switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
        case 'field_zoekproduct_field' :

          $element['searchfield'] = array(
            '#title' => t('Zoek naar een product'),
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#required' => TRUE,
            '#maxlength' => 115,
            '#size' => 55,
            '#weight' => 0,
            '#default_value' => 'zoek...',
            "#executes_submit_callback" => FALSE,
            '#attributes' => array('onfocus' => "this.value = '';"),  //when textbox gets focus the default value will be removed
            '#ajax' => array(
                  'event' => 'change',
                  'callback' => 'zoekproduct_zoek_getypte_text',
                  'keypress' => true,
                  'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
                ),
        );

  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback must look like this
zoekproduct_zoek_getypte_text($form, &$form_state){}

check what values you receive in $form_state or $form